# Trouble installing ros-indigo-ros-base in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS-Base in Ubuntu 16.04. Here are my steps:

> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116

> sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base -y

I keep getting a `E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-base` error. Is indigo still available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296320/trouble-installing-ros-indigo-ros-base-in-ubuntu-16.04/) by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check the [install page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) carfefully: Indigo is not supported on Ubuntu 16.04:

> ROS Indigo **ONLY** supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04) for debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1